# wp_mail with dynamic receiver don't work

Tags: php, wordpress

I think it is a stupid mistake which I can't see right now.

This is my code:

```
    $berater_id = get_the_ID();
    $berater_mail = get_post_meta($berater_id,'dmd_consulter_mail',true);
    wp_mail($berater_mail, 'Buchungsanfrage', $content, $headers);
```

Output of `$berater_mail`:

var_dump -> `string(21) "a.bla@bla.de"`

var_export -> `'a.bla@bla.de'`

echo -> `a.bla@bla.de`

So it seems that the variable is correct. But I don't get any mails.

If I replace the `$berater_mail` with the e-mail (a.bla@bla.de) it works fine.

Comment: Is that the real email address?  If so, the "21" in the `var_dump()` looks strange - it should be 12 (`$berater_mail = 'a.bla@bla.de'; var_dump($berater_mail);` gives `string(12) "a.bla@bla.de"`) - any chance the stored value contains an HTML tag that's hidden when you echo it?

Comment: It won't send any email if you are missing contents. There is no issue with your email id.